Trouble with Unit Testing Apache Camel 3.14.7 Routes Using Blueprint XML and Java Beans
I'm working on a project using Apache Camel 3.14.7, combining Blueprint XML and Java beans for route definitions. I'm facing an issue with unit testing these routes, they involve complex operations like database interactions and bean processing. I attempted to use CamelBlueprintTestSupport for testing, but I consistently encounter a null context issue, rendering this approach ineffective. My guess is that this might be due to CamelBlueprintTestSupport being outdated, as it seems to target up to Camel version 3.1.0. I noticed that the camel-test-infra is aimed at versions 3.16 and up, potentially leaving a gap for my version.
Given the complexities involved in my route, which includes database calls, bean method invocations, and custom processors, I'm searching for a testing strategy that supports full Blueprint XML route testing without involving Spring.
Here's an example snippet from my route for context:
<camelContext id="stFA" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<route id="rStr">
    <from uri="servlet://...."/>
    <to uri="sql-stored:dbo.sp....."/>
    <bean ref="fabO" method="transformTo(${body})" />
    <to uri="sql:insert into..."/>
    <process ref="formatJsonObjectsToJsonArrays"/>
</route>

This route doesn't make sense, it's just for completness.
Is there a known testing approach or workaround that can cater to the specific needs of Apache Camel 3.14.7 with Blueprint XML routes?

When unit testing camel routes you can use advicewith to replace any camel-sql or camel-jdbc endpoints on a route with a simple mock-response. Queries typically return body of type List<Map<String, Object>> or List<outputClass> and updates return null.
List<ExampleModel> mockQueryResponse = createExampleResponseForTest();
AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, "exampleRoute", a -> {
                
    a.weaveByToUri("sql:*")
        .replace()
        .setHeader(SqlConstants.SQL_ROW_COUNT).constant(mockQueryResponse.size())
        .setBody().constant(mockQueryResponse)
    ;
});

When using adviceWith remember to override is isUseAdviceWith method to return true and start routes manually before template.send calls
@Override
public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
}

Now since many blueprints often have references to OSGi services you'll likely have to mock those in order for CamelBlueprintTestSupport to work. This can be done by overriding one of the addServicesOnStartup methods.
Example mocking OSGi JMS and DataSource services using Mockito mocking framework.
@Override
protected void addServicesOnStartup(Map<String, KeyValueHolder<Object, Dictionary>> services) {

    // Mock artemis and datasource services just to satisfy 
    // OSGi service dependencies. 
    Properties mockArtemisProperties = new Properties();
    mockArtemisProperties.put("name", "artemis");

    services.put(ConnectionFactory.class.getCanonicalName(), 
        asService(mock(ConnectionFactory.class), mockArtemisProperties));

    Properties mockDatasourceProperties = new Properties();
    mockDatasourceProperties.put("dataSourceName", "exampleDatabase");

    services.put(ConnectionFactory.class.getCanonicalName(), 
        asService(mock(DataSource.class), mockDatasourceProperties));

    super.addServicesOnStartup(services);
}

Mocking the database responses will mean that sql-queries will no longer be tested against a real database. However I would generally consider stuff like camel-test-infra out of scope for unit and integration tests.
If you're using lightweight databases like sqlite or H2 you can easily create temporary database for test using Junits @TempDir feature.
